# Can I build an chrome extension from an existing React application?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, build

So I have an existing Create React Application and I want to be able to build a chrome extension to work in conjunction with it. Is there a away I can use webpack or something so that my extension kind "lives in" the React application? I want to do this because the existing application is quite large and I don't want to have to make changes (UI, api, or otherwise) twice. In my head I'm picturing it something like this:

```
- MyApplication/
  - src/
    - index.html
    - App.tsx
    - components/
    - <bunch of other useful stuff>
  - extension/
    - index.html
    - Extension.tsx (equivalent of App.tsx in react app)
```

Basically I'd be able to import whatever I need into the extension and run some command like `build extension` and it would bundle just the files and dependencies imported and necessary for the extension and output that to some directory I can upload to the Chrome Web Store.

I also briefly considered splitting the application into into something like `MyApplication-core`,  `MyApplication-web`, and `MyApplication-extension` or something and just installing `core` in both `web` and `extension` but not sure if that's the best strategy or not. The first strategy I outlined seems simpler to maintain but I could be wrong.

Also, if there is another strategy I haven't thought of please let me know! Happy to add clarification if necessary as well! TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Just build it and add manifest with required configurations. After this you will have posibility to load it as an extension.